# React inline switch statement default case does not work when rendering components

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I noticed that the inline switch for react does not render

This was my implementation, even though it enters the default code block, it does not render the component correctly. ReportExportButton renders fine and enters the code block.

```js
{
   {
     [Report.Report1]: (
       <ReportExportButton
         handleExport={handleExport}
         isDisabled={isDisableSubmit}
       />
     ),
     default: <DefaultExportButton />,
   }[currentReport]/>
}
```

This was my fix for this but is there a better way of doing this?

```js
{
   {
     [Report.Report1]: (
       <ReportExportButton
         handleExport={handleExport}
         isDisabled={isDisableSubmit}
       />
     ),
   }[currentReport] || <DefaultExportButton />
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't currentReport value be equal to "default" for the <DefaultExportButton /> to be returned in the first case? The second snippet you posted looks correct.

Comment: No, in my case if the current case is not present, it still goes into the default case, it's just that the button isn't rendered correctly or at all.